# Onedrive, store custom properties/attribute within a file

Tags: c#, onedrive

Is there a way to store custom properties within a file I upload? i.e. I need a simple way to store a metadata for the files I upload.

The only way I found is, to store the data in the "description" property, like:

```
string id = await FetchFileId(fileName);
var fileData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
fileData.Add("description", "here goes json data or something similar");            
LiveOperationResult operationResult = await client.PutAsync(id, fileData);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Ryan from OneDrive here - What sort of data would you like to store associated w/ a file? I ask because it's something on our backlog and I'm collecting use cases.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your responce! Well, I have an app, it stores the data as separate files, each file is a sqlite db file. When the app starts it enumerates the folder on onedrive and shows the files. What I would like to add, when I upload the file I would like to store summary metadata for the db. I would preffer json in this case. The summary data would contain: for instance, how many rows in the table1, how many new records have been inserted etc. So I can access to this info without downloading the db itself.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no supported way to set custom metadata right now. We don't recommend using the 'description' property for that, either, as it's meant to be a human-readable description that's displayed in OneDrive apps.